what are proper steps for adding git tag to a commit in bash?
I need to start adding a tag to my commits... I use bash shell.  what is the proper sequence
I did it like this:
git tag <verbiage>
git commit <verbiage>

Is this correct?

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging

It's correct if you want to add a tag to the parent of the commit you are about to create.

You'd usually create a tag to point to a commit after you created it:
# Do some work

# Stage the files
git add relevant_file_1.txt relevant_file_2.txt

# Commit it
git commit -m "Version 1 ready"

# tag that commit
git tag version_1


Not only usually :-) It's logically impossible to tag a non-existent yet commit.

So make my commit then create the tag... got it!
